# Flutter determine direct parent Widget class from context

Tags: flutter, boolean, parent

Is it possible to use the context of a child Widget to determine whether the class name of its parent is a specific Widget.

Something like:

```
bool parentTypeisParentContainer = context.isParentWidget(ParentContainer);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is not a good idea for a child to be dependent on a parent.

Comment: The child is another instance of the same parent widget if it is not null. I am trying to establish whether it is the de facto master or not. That is whether it is the first first occurrence of this Widget or whether it is the child of a parent that is also this Widget. This alters certain styles. It's not massively important but it would just save a little boilerplate.